# Unable to replace Special character using Sed Command

Tags: linux, sed

I have to replace word `Check` with `protected/note/run.json` from book.txt file but I am receiving error.

```
sed -i 's/Check/protected/note/run.json/g' book.txt

Error: sed: -e expression #1, char 24: unknown option to `s'
```

Can someone please let me how to replace `Check` with `protected/note/run.json`.

Comment: Switch from `s///` to `s|||`.